# How to perform modular exponentiation when residue of exponent is provided?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have to perform the computation of $a^{b}\pmod {m}$. However, instead of providing $b$ directly, I instead know the value of $b\mod {m}$. Is it even possible to perform this calculation and if so, how do I go about it?

EDIT: I know that $m$ is a prime number.

Comment: No, it is not possible.  Take $m=3$.  then $1\equiv 4\pmod 3$ but $2^1\not \equiv 2^4\pmod 3$.  For prime $m$ what you need is $b\pmod {m-1}$.

Comment: @lulu can you expand a little on how I can do the calculation if I know $ b \pmod {m - 1} $?

Comment: Assume that $a\not \equiv 0\pmod m$.  Then $a^{m-1}\equiv 1 \pmod m$, by Little Fermat.  Thus if you replace $b$ with $b+k(m-1)$ we get $a^{b+k(m-1)}=a^b\times \left(a^{m-1}\right)^k\equiv a^b\pmod m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, this is not possible.  Taking $m=3,\;a=2$ we remark that $$2^1\not \equiv 2^4\pmod 3$$

What you need is $b\pmod {m-1}$:

Assume that $a\not \equiv 0\pmod m$.  Then $a^{m-1}\equiv 1 \pmod m$, by Little Fermat.  Thus if you replace $b$ with $b+k(m-1)$ we get $a^{b+k(m-1)}=a^b\times \left(a^{m-1}\right)^k\equiv a^b\pmod m$.